# Extracting century and year from a string

Tags: r, string, function

I have a large column displaying a string such as:

> 20-1843PA-HY-4563-214DF

The "20" is the century while the "18 is the year. What is the simplest way to extract these two using a function and have an output of 2018 in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the digits as a group from the start (`^`) of the string followed by the `-`, then capture the two digits (`(\\d{2})`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1\\2`) of the captured group

```
f1 <- function(nm) as.numeric(sub("^(\\d+)-(\\d{2}).*", "\\1\\2", nm))
f1(str1)
#[1] 2018
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "20-1843PA-HY-4563-214DF"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
chr_collumn<-"20-1843PA-HY-4563-214DF"
chr_collumn<-strsplit(chr_collumn,"-")
chr_collumn<-unlist(chr_collumn)[1:2]
chr_year<-paste0(chr_collumn[1],strtrim(chr_collumn[2],width=2))
chr_year<-as.numeric(chr_year)
chr_year
```